# Save all PDF-files in a folder as JPG-files using PDF24 (pdf24-Creator.exe) and Command-line

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd

I know that PDF24 is able to convert PDF to JPG. But I don't get how I can convert using a command line for `pdf24-Creator.exe`, from PDF to JPG?

I'd prefer to use PDF24 than Imagick - because PDF24 converts much better and faster (manually).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
@For /R "C:\Users\vladi\PDF_TO_JPG\" %%G In (*.pdf) Do @For %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do @"%ProgramFiles%\PDF24\pdf24-Creator.exe" -outputFile "%%~nG_.jpg" "%%G"
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you asking if a program which is essentially named PDF Creator, can be used to create a JPG? Or are you telling us that it does, but the correct options for doing so, are not working?

Comment: What is it that you expect your code to do that it is not doing, or doing that you did not expect? What error message are you receiving,

Comment: What is the inner `for` loop for when you are not using its reference `%%H`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer (Part 1) to what is wrong is remove redundant part

**Q)** includes `Do @For %%H In ("%%~dpG.")`

```
@For /R "C:\Users\vladi\PDF_TO_JPG\" %%G In (*.pdf) Do @For %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do @"%ProgramFiles%\PDF24\pdf24-Creator.exe" -outputFile "%%~nG_.jpg" "%%G"
```

**A)** remove that redundant part and pdf creator will work through the file list

```
@For /R "C:\Users\vladi\PDF_TO_JPG\" %%G In (*.pdf) Do  @"%ProgramFiles%\PDF24\pdf24-Creator.exe" -outputFile "%%~nG_.jpg" "%%G"
```

**A)** Part 2

PDF24-creator.exe is the GUI command for PDF24 Application Suite/Compendium, however, the command line interface is [pdf24-DocTool.exe [options] [file1] [file2] ...](https://creator.pdf24.org/manual/11/#pdf24-doctoolexe)

It does some tasks silently, such as command line print, but `-convert-to` will call up the dialog box for selecting an output image file type / profile (such as png or jpg) so the user can enter resolution, colors etc.

The suite includes several alternative command line routes to process different filetypes in the background, and for that particular task employs  qpdf to write a temporary file without DRM restrictions (e.g. qpdf: wrote file %localappdata%\Temp\PDF24\unlocked_0_#########_##########.pdf), then a GhostScript conversion.

```
GPL Ghostscript 10.02.0 (2023-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through ##.
```

So it also includes the latest GhostScript thus it may be better/faster to write directly a gswin##c.exe command line that will include [device JPG](https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#JFIF) and your desired other settings such as resolution. But that's a question answered many times here in Stack-overflow https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ghostscript+sDEVICE+jpeg

PDF24 uses this syntax for save as
PNG (-sDEVICE=png16m -r### ... ... -%04d.png)
or
JPG (-sDEVICE=jpeg -r### -dJPEGQ=## ... ... -%04d.jpg)

```
"%ProgramFiles%\PDF24\gs\gswinc.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY "-sFONTPATH=C:\WINDOWS\Fonts;C:\Users\ name \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts" -dNEWPDF=true -sDEVICE=jpeg -r150 -dJPEGQ=95 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-sOutputFile=C:\ target dir \filename-%04d.jpg" "C:\Users\ name \AppData\Local\Temp\PDF24\unlocked_0_#########_##########.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare yourself a profile, for example, “jpg150”, you can use this command:

```
"c:\Program Files\PDF24\pdf24-DocTool.exe" -convertTopdf -expandDirs . -outputDir . -noprogress -applyProfile -profile user/jpg150
```

This command converts all PDFs in the current directory to 150 dpi JPG with the same names. This option is, IMHO, better because you don’t need to manage any filenames.